# mapbox-gl supercluster getLeaves

Tags: mapbox

At a certain level, some can trigger, others can not trigger.

[image: right image],

[image: error iamge],

They are at the same scale at the zoom level.

I'm not sure if it's the problem. [#72](https://github.com/mapbox/supercluster/issues/72)

Here's the problem code

```
        var cluster_id = properties.cluster_id,
            zoom = Math.floor(map.getZoom()),
            pointsInCluster;
        cluster_id = (cluster_id << 5) + (zoom + 1);

        pointsInCluster = cluster.getLeaves(cluster_id, Infinity, 0);
```

Here is Reappearance of the problem  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aznkw784/50/)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is properly clear. Redit with appropriate description and bring your code in the description as well, wrap it with code highlighter , wherever required.